# Discrepancy in unix date command and java simpledateformat

Tags: java, unix

If I am running unix command

```
echo 1378223625 | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date -d "@{}" "+%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M %Z"
```

result is `03-09-2013-17-53 CEST`

If I am running from java

```
public class DateExperiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-H-m z");
        System.out.println(df.format(1378223625) );
    }
}
```

my result is `16-01-1970-23-50 CET`

unix command gives correct result but java is giving me wrong result.

Can anybody explain why am getting this discrepancy? what is the mistake?

Comment: `but java is giving me wrong result`. No, your expectations are wrong.

Comment: Another good example of why one should not use a count-since-[epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) to handle date-time values.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a numerical value as an argument to `SimpleDateFormat#format(..)`, it uses the [`Date` constructor which expects a `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date-long-). That constructor

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

The value you provided represents

```
16-01-1970-23-50 CET
```

The problem here is that you have seconds, not milliseconds.

You'll want

```
System.out.println(df.format(1378223625000L));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unix is giving you the time in seconds since epoch, Java is expecting milliseconds. I get your expected output if I multiply by 1000.

```
System.out.println(df.format(1378223625*1000L));
```

Outputs

```
03-09-2013-11-53 EDT
```